# Retrieve SVG Dom in object element as text

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to figure out how to retrieve the whole svg-dom as text in a variable via Javascript.

I have no problems to reference the embedded svg file. But innerHTML or outerHTML on the SVG Element will not work and I hope that I don't have to loop through all child nodes and every single attribute.

Reason for my question:

I would like to offer the visitors of my page and my students the svg code which is dynamically modified by user actions.

You may take a look at the example of Pythagoras on my site: [SVG sample with Pythagoras triangle](http://bemeup.de/rwd.html)

Thanks in advance for you help! It's my first question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<object />` element you're using to embed the SVG file effectively acts as a document container, and has its own DOM. You can access the SVG element this way:

```
var objectElement = svgrwd; // or document.getElementById("svgrwd");
var svgDOM = objectElement.contentDocument;
var svgElement = svgDOM.documentElement; // returns the <svg /> element
var html = svgElement.outerHTML;

// or

svgrwd.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Read more about the `object` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement